# Наследование шаблонов в Twig

Tags: twig, php

Как наследовать шаблоны?
Например, это основной шаблон `main.tpl`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>{% block title %}Test Application{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
{% block sidebar %}
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

А это дочерний шаблон `children.tpl`

```
{% extends 'main.tpl' %}

{% block title %}My cool blog posts{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% for entry in blog_entries %}
<h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Но при выводе так

```
$tpl = $twig->loadTemplate('children.tpl');

echo $tpl->render(array('re' => 'Ура' ));
```

Выдает ошибку

> шаблон, который расширяет другой не может иметь тело в "children.tpl"

Но при выводе основного шаблона всё нормально.
Думаю, что с загрузкой шаблона что-то напутал. И надо ли дочерний шаблон загружать?  
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, зачем приведен перевод ошибки. В оригинале звучит так:

> A template that extends another one cannot have a body in ...

Данная ошибка проявляется только если в дочернем шаблоне имеется контент вне тегов `{% block %} {% endblock %}`. Игнорируются пробелы, переводы строки и табуляция. Однако неразрывный пробел может дать подобную ошибку.

Дочерний шаблон можно заранее не загружать, а передать первым параметром метода `render`